# Uploadify + Paperclip + Rails nested association before_save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, uploadify

I need to create a model application form where models can fill it and add pictures to it.

I'm following this example with Uploadify, Paperclip and Rails 3 approach.
https://github.com/websymphony/Rails3-Paperclip-Uploadify

To the pictures, i have an polymorphic Attachment model and i would like to attach those ajax uploaded attachments to the yet unsaved model form and there's is where the tricky part cames.

Users are not logged, so there's no "model_id" until is saved.

Since i'm showing the user a small preview of the images that he uploaded in the form by ajax after each upload i need some way to correlate them.

I was thinking about some middle token until the model is saved but i'm not sure whats the best approach to accomplish this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

We dumped Uploadify when moving to Rails 3 and are now using jQuery-File-Upload.

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Setting up a bunch of middleware to do nothing more than upload files seems like a major hassle.

Only problem with the jquery solution is multiple uploads aren't supported in IE.

Comment: Do you think you'd be able to give some information regarding how you tied paperclip and jquery-File-Upload?

Comment: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/jQuery-File-Upload-for-Rails-3